# AWS S3 sync creates objects with different permissions than bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to use an S3 bucket to upload files to as part of a build, it is configured to provide files as a static site and the content is protected using a Lambda and CloudFront. When I manually create files in the bucket they are all visible and everything is happy, but when the files are uploaded what is created are not available, resulting in an access denied response.

The user that's pushing to the bucket does not belong in the same AWS environment, but it has been set up with an ACL that allows it to push to the bucket, and the bucket with a policy that allows it to be pushed to by that user.

The command that I'm using is:

```sh
aws s3 sync --no-progress --delete docs/_build/html "s3://my-bucket" --acl bucket-owner-full-control
```

Is there something else that I can try that basically uses the bucket permissions for anything that's created?

Comment: Does the user belong to a different aws account?

Comment: @jellycsc yes, it does. I used "environment" but meant "account"

Comment: Ok, it seems like a bucket owner permission issue. Try following [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/add-object-ownership.html) guide and set `Object Ownership` to `Bucket owner preferred`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to OP's feedback in the comment section, setting `Object Ownership` to `Bucket owner preferred` fixed the issue.